# How do I most efficiently maintain my weapons in System Shock 2?

Tags: system-shock-2

Gee what a game,

Ammo is scarce enough as it is, but I have so far been able to scavenge enough. However, my guns are breaking down and I only have a few repair tools left for them. The repair tools also seem to give me a single point to my guns so far which is not satisfactory. How can I keep my guns in usable condition in an efficient manner?

Comment: I'd recommend just editing the user.cfg as cloudymusic instructs and eliminating degradation entirely. The incredibly fast rate that your weapons break down is one of SS2's very few flaws.

Comment: @DanC I'd disagree. I find the high rate of degradation to be one of the key factors reinforcing SS2's greatest strength - *scarcity* - of weapons, of ammo, of health, of everything, is what reinforces the environment of terror that makes the game so great. Keep in mind that a gun at condition 1 and a gun at condition 10 do identical damage - so you really just need to keep things from breaking, and use melee judiciously.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To clarify terminology, repair tools are used to repair broken/jammed weapons, while maintenance tools are used to improve the condition (0-10 rating) of weapons.

Putting points into Maintenance skill will give you more bang for your buck from maintenance tools; a certain level of Maintenance skill is also necessary to be able to maintain certain weapons. You can also minimize the amount of repairing you have to do by opting to use melee weapons instead of guns when possible.

If this still gives you trouble and/or you just don't want to deal with it (which I can certainly understand!), it's also possible to reduce or disable weapon degradation by editing `user.cfg` in your game's install directory (creating it if there isn't already one) and adding the following line:

`gun_degrade_rate <n>`

...where `<n>` is a number between `0` and `1`: `0` disables degradation entirely, while `1` degrades at full speed. (For example, `0.5` would degrade at half the normal rate.)

Patched versions of the game will contain a document called `readmep.wri` in their root install directory that provides more information.

Comment: 25% degradation rate plays much better.